# Bootstrap 5.1 Navmenu collapses and then immediately opens again

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor Server Application. I am using Bootstrap. I have this sidebar navigation menu that I take an example of https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/# collapsible for the sidebar. The problem is when I click the buttons (home, orders, vendors, customers, administration) on the navmenu, it closes and then immediately opens again. I tried to identify the problem with browser developer tools but had no luck. How can I fix it? And make the sidebar collapsed by default.

Here is the navmenu

```
<main class="sidebarmain">
<div class="flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-white" style="width: 280px;">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-3 link-dark text-decoration-none border-bottom">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="30" height="24">
            <use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use>
        </svg>
        @*<span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Collapsible</span>*@
    </a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
        <li class="mb-1">
            <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#home-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
                Home
            </button>
            <div class="collapse show" id="home-collapse">
                <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/" class="link-dark rounded">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-1">
            <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dashboard-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                Orders
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="dashboard-collapse" style="">
                <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/orders" class="link-dark rounded">Order List</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/upload" class="link-dark rounded">Order Upload</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/report" class="link-dark rounded">Report</a>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-1">
            <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#vendors-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                Vendors
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="vendors-collapse">
                <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/vendors" class="link-dark rounded">Vendor Management</a>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-1">
            <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#customers-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                Customers
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="customers-collapse">
                <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/customers" class="link-dark rounded">Customer Management</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
        <li class="mb-1">
            <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#account-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                Administration
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="account-collapse">
                <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/administration" class="link-dark rounded">User Management</a>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is _Layout.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace IMS.WebApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <base href="~/"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="IMS.WebApp.styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default.css">
    <link href="css/sidebars.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered"/>

</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
        An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
        An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
    </environment>
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
<script src="~/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/myjs.js"></script>

<script>
    window.downloadFileFromStream = async (fileName, contentStreamReference) => {
        const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
        const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
        anchorElement.href = url;
        anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
        anchorElement.click();
        anchorElement.remove();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is sidebar.css

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.sidebarmain {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100vh;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.b-example-divider {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.bi {
  vertical-align: -.125em;
  pointer-events: none;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.dropdown-toggle { outline: 0; }

.nav-flush .nav-link {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-toggle {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
.btn-toggle:hover,
.btn-toggle:focus {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
  background-color: #d2f4ea;
}

.btn-toggle::before {
  width: 1.25em;
  line-height: 0;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='rgba%280,0,0,.5%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M5 14l6-6-6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  transition: transform .35s ease;
  transform-origin: .5em 50%;
}

.btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
}
.btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.btn-toggle-nav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: .1875rem .5rem;
  margin-top: .125rem;
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-toggle-nav a:hover,
.btn-toggle-nav a:focus {
  background-color: #d2f4ea;
}

.scrollarea {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.fw-semibold { font-weight: 600; }
.lh-tight { line-height: 1.25; }
```

## Edit 1

I did a little trial and error on the _Layout.cshtml. When I remove this `<link href="IMS.WebApp.styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` page structure is broken but menu worked correctly. Where is this **IMS.WebApp.styles.css**?

[image]

## Edit 2

CSS isolation occurs at build time. Blazor rewrites CSS selectors to match markup rendered by the component. The rewritten CSS styles are bundled and produced as a static asset.
[Blazor CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#css-isolation-bundling)

## Edit3

Removing this from NavMenu.Razor.css solved my problem.

```
/*.collapse {
    /* Never collapse the sidebar for wide screens */
    display: block;
}*/
```